# Date formatting with Swift Decode protocol

Tags: json, swift4, alamofire, decode

I am trying to get a date from JSON into a structure in Swift 4 via Alamofire. I have setup a date formatter which matches the JSON format, but I get an error raised: `Date string does not match format expected by formatter`

I am using the following code:

```
struct AgentEvent: Decodable {
    let callref: Int?
    let repdate: Date?
    let parked: Bool?
    let company: String?
}

let decoder = JSONDecoder()
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"
decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .formatted(dateFormatter)

self.events = try! decoder.decode([AgentEvent].self, from: data!)
```

Sample JSON (Confirmed when running method in browser) used is:

```
{"callref":142,
"company":"Test Company Ltd",
"repdate":"2019-01-25T17:21:00",...
```

I've breakpointed the code to see exactly what data I am trying to decode (in case it had been translated somewhere) and the date format is being passed in and it is: 
"2019-01-25T17:21:00" so as far as I can see the format does match the expected format in the formatter. I can't see what is wrong here?

Comment: Please show entire actual JSON.

Comment: Not sure how that will help as it's repdate that its failing on, but: 

[{"callref":142,"company":"Test Company Ltd","repdate":"2019-01-25T17:21:00","attended":"2019-01-25T17:21:00","calltype":15,"status":1,"summary":"test another new event, for organisation value","finflag":null,"parked":false,"Prioritized":false,"Agent_Id":2,"AgentGroup_Id":null,"IsRecurring":0},

Comment: I literally copied then pasted your code and JSON into _Playground_ and it parses the date correctly, and prints it on the console as `Optional(2019-01-25 17:21:00 +0000)`

Comment: Whats the purpose behind declaring all properties as optionals? You should only declare optional the properties from your json that  might not have any vale returned.

Comment: Because this record represents the lifetime of an event so most of the values can be null at one point or another.

Comment: @TonyLaw You need to set your date formatter locale to `"en_US_POSIX"`. Your device locale and settings might affect the a fixed date format if you don't set the locale to the computer locale (POSIX). I suspect your device had the 24h time settings turned off.

Answer (score -1):

Turns out that dateDecodingStrategy doesn't seem to like working with the date formatting I was using. I had to write a custom initialiser instead and handle the formatting in there.

Works fine now.